# Wordpress Roles > Allow Editors to Edit Themes?

Tags: wordpress

Can someone tell me of a way in which I can add a user to have access to my blog's admin area and manage themes without being the administrator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a nice plugin "Role Manager", but AFAIK it's no longer actively maintained.

Maybe this one works with current releases ("Capability Manager"):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/capsman/

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the quick help.

It appears to be incredibly powerful. However, there is one thing I cant figure out how to do. I want to give the user the ability to manage themes, but not edit them. My theme's manage button is outside the appearance tab on the main dashboard level.